# Unable to use underscore module in parse.com

Tags: parse-platform

I try to use underscore :

```
 <% if (!_.isEmpty(comments)) { %>
  <h2>All Comments</h2>
  <% comments.forEach(function(comment) { %>
    <% include ../admin/_comment %>
  <% }) %>
<% } else { %>
  <p>No comments yet.</p>
<% } %>
```

I add in the controller (comments here) the following code :

```
var _ = require('cloud/libs/underscore-min');
```

and in the app.js

```
var _ = require('cloud/libs/underscore-min');
```

But I get this error :

```
_ is not defined
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (ejs.js:256:12), <anonymous>:31:214)
at ejs.js:261:15
at Object.exports.render (ejs.js:299:13)
at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (ejs.js:325:22)
at View.render (express_view.js:77:8)
at Function.app.render (express_application.js:516:10)
at res.render (express_response.js:763:7)
at e.<anonymous> (controllers/gift.js:9:17)
at e.i (Parse.js:14:27703)
at e.a.value (Parse.js:14:27063)
```

Can you help me ?

Thank you !

Comment: Use another name for your variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have forget to add this in main.js :

```
app.locals.underscore = underscore;
```

and I change the name "_" to "underscore", thanks to Flavio Filho.